# Text to Speech in Netlogo

Tags: text-to-speech, netlogo

I am creating a program in Netlogo in which I am initializing a variable. The value stored in this variable changes when a function is called. I want that whenever the function is called, the value stored in the variable is pronounced/spoken. I already know how to call external .wav file in Netlogo, but can I pronounce/speak the variable value (**say 250**) as **"two hundred and fifty**" at any time?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno about other OS's, but Mac OS X has a command called `say` that does text-to-speech, so you could use the [Shell extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Shell-Extension/#readme) to invoke that.

There was an old NetLogo 4.0 extension, also Mac OS X only, that supported text-to-speech directly: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/4.0.0/extensions/speech.tgz. But I don't think anybody ever updated it for newer versions of NetLogo.

Comment: Thank you Sir. This is a good extension. I am using Windows OS. So If anyone can please tell me an extension for it, that would be useful for me. Anyways thank you so much for the help